# D3: Adding second Y-axis, limit x-axis ticks to only 2

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

Using D3 v.3, I'd like to eliminate all but two tick labels on the x-axis and place the first directly under the y-axis and the second under a secondary y-axis as shown in the screenshot. I understand that the `.ticks(count)` function will not necessarily give you the number of ticks that you ask for.  How can I get just two ticks and place each as I described?

Here is how I am generating the x-axis:

```
// Set the ranges
var xScale = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale)
  .orient("bottom")
  .ticks(2)
  .tickFormat(formatTime);
```

(I am not limited to v.3, but I am not sure what might be affected in my existing code by switching to v.4).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ticks` is not the best approach, because:

1. It *"returns **approximately** count representative values from the scale's input domain"* (quoting the API, emphasis mine)
2. You cannot control **where** the ticks will be generated.

**Solution**:

If you pass the `xScale` domain to the `tickValues` function you'll have only the first and the last dates in the axis:

```
.tickValues(xScale.domain())
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var xScale = d3.time.scale().range([30, 470])
  .domain([new Date(2016, 00, 01), new Date(2017, 11, 01)]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickValues(xScale.domain())
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.time.format("%b %Y")(d);
  });

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(xAxis)
```

```css
path,
line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```